# setInterval not working on ajax call second time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Jquery**:

```
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    refreshChat()
}, 1000);

function refreshChat() {
    var lastItem = 0;
    var ptags = document.querySelectorAll('.chatmessage');

    [].forEach.call(ptags, function(ptags) {
        lastItem = ptags.val();
    });

    $(".messagefeed").append(lastItem);


    $.post("outputPages/fetchChat.php", {
        'li': lastItem
    }, function(response) {
        $(".messagefeed").append(response);
    });
    alert("IS AJAX CALL RUNNING? YES");
}
```

**fetchChat.php**:

```
<?PHP
require "../pages/connect.php";

$li = $_POST;
$li = implode($li);

$fetch = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE messageID >= '$li' ORDER BY messageID ";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($fetch)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $ID = $row['messageID'];
        $date = $row['messageDate'];
        $persona = $row['messagePersona'];
        $message = $row['message'];

        echo "<p class='chatmessage' value='$ID'>$date;
        $persona: $message</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

This call works the first time, but only then. It never calls again. If I comment all of my javascript and uncomment line by line, the 2nd call only stops working when I reach the ajax call. I have tried putting dies and exits in my php but that doesn't fix it. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Change your setIntervalline to bellow.

`var myVar = setInterval("refreshChat()", 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

A paragraph `p` cannot have a value attribute and based on your comments, this seems to be causing your problems.

Also note that your value can break your html so you should encode your output correctly.

An easy and valid solution for the ID's is to use data attributes:

php

```
// you should do this for all variables to make sure they cannot break your html
$message = htmlspecialchars($row['message'], ENT_QUOTES);
...
echo "<p class='chatmessage' data-value='$ID'>$date;
    $persona: $message</p>";
```

And in javascript you can get the value of the last one without a loop:

```
lastitem = $(".chatmessage:last-child").data('value');
```

Also note that it is not a good idea to use an interval for your ajax calls. If a call takes longer than expected, you can run into problems as multiple requests will run simultaneously. It is better to set a timeOut and set that again in the success function of your ajax call.

Comment: My ajax works now, and it loops, but it returns the same chat messages everytime the new one is called. That's why I want it to get the value of the last message and make the select query only higher than that, so it knows which messages to send to the user.

Comment: @ETurns You should change `>=` to `>` in your query. And does the javascript I posted give you the correct value? Also, why are you appending that value to your message feed?